# XML modification in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am automating XML comparision using Powershell (4.0). I am finding problem in XML modification. We have to take Production XML and replicate in non production. Some node values are different so we can't copy paste. Below is sample xml section.

I have to compare section name of both the files and make changes as per Production file. Below is my code.

```
$live_web_config = "\dummy path\web.config"
$int_web_config = "\Script_test\web.config"
$live_xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$int_xml = New-Object -TypeName XML
$live_xml.Load($live_web_config)
$int_xml.Load($int_web_config)
foreach ($sec in $live_xml.configuration.configSections.section.name)
{
    $node = $int_xml.configuration.configSections.section | where {$_.name -imatch $sec }
    if ($node)
    {
        continue
    }
    else
    {
        #write-host $sec "not found in int"
        $add_node = $int_xml.importnode("section")
    write-host $sec
    $add_node = $live_xml.configuration.configSections.section | where {$_.name -eq $sec }
    $int_xml.appendchild($add_node)
    $int_xml.save($int_web_config)
    }
}
```

This code returns me following error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\vijay.patel\myscripts\file_copy.ps1:86 char:3
+         $int_xml.section.appendchild($add_node)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you provide the full script? I`m missing the definition of $add_node

Comment: Yeah i missed that one.`$add_node = $int_xml.importnode("section")`

Comment: The line in that error message doesn't appear anywhere in the snippet you provided. Is there more code you didn't give us?

Comment: still miss the whole script. Maybe you have to change line 86 from "$int_xml.section.appendchild($add_node)" to "$int_xml.configuration.configSections.section.appendchild($add_node)" ?

Comment: Yeah. I made a lot of changes to the code. Current code is 
`$add_node = $int_xml.importnode("section")
 write-host $sec
 $add_node = $live_xml.configuration.configSections.section | where {$_.name -eq $sec }
$int_xml.appendchild($add_node)
$int_xml.save($int_web_config)`
I am getting syntax error for this code in second line. If any one can suggest better way to add the missing node in second file that will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can't call `ImportNode()` with one string argument. The method expects an `XmlNode` object and a second parameter indicating whether the cloned node should include child nodes as well. Also, if you filter the sections from the live config for those nodes that are not present in the internal config you can avoid having to use `continue` inside the loop. Plus, you need to append the new node below `configSections`, not in the document root, and you should save the modified document just once *after* the loop has finished.

```bsh
$int_sections = $int_xml.configuration.configSections.section.name
$live_xml.configuration.configSections.section | Where-Object {
    $int_sections -notcontains $_.name
} | ForEach-Object {
    $node = $int_xml.ImportNode($_, $true)
    [void]$int_xml.configuration.configSections.AppendChild($node)
}
$int_xml.Save($int_web_config)
```

Comment: Thanks Asgar for your time. Your code returns error at appendchild method.
`Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'appendchild'.
At C:\Users\vijay.patel\myscripts\file_copy.ps1:75 char:3
+   $int_xml.configuration.configSections.appendchild($node)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound`

Comment: By providing "xpath" I was able to find a solution for it. Thanks again for your help.